# Matrix multiplication is slower when multithreading in Julia

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, julia

I am working with big matrices (size of 30k rows and ~100 columns). I am doing some matrix multiplication and the process would take around 20 seconds. This is my code:

```
@time begin
    result = -1
    data = -1

    for i=1:size
        first_matrix = @view data[i * split,:]

        for j=1:size
            second_matrix = @view Qg[j * split,:]
            matrix_multiplication = first_matrix * second_matrix'
            current_sum = sum(matrix_multiplication)
            global result

            if current_sum > result
                result = current_sum
                data = matrix_multiplication[1,1]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Trying to optimize this a little more, I tried to use multi-threading (julia --thread 4) to get better performance.

```
@time begin
    global result = -1
    global data = -1
    lock = ReentrantLock()

    for i=1:size
        first_matrix = @view data[i * split,:]

        Threads.@threads for j=1:size
            second_matrix = @view Qg[j * split,:]
            matrix_multiplication = first_matrix * second_matrix'
            current_sum = sum(matrix_multiplication)
            global result

            if current_sum > result
                lock(lock)
                result = current_sum
                data = matrix_multiplication[1,1]
                unlock(lock)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

By adding multi-threading I thought I would get an increase in performance, but the performance got worse (~40 seconds). I removed the lock to see if that was the issue, but still got the same performance. I am running this on a Dual-Core Intel Core i5 (MacBook pro). Does anyone know why my multi-threading code doesn't work?

Comment: Julia by default uses OpenBLAS for matrix multiplication which internally uses multithreading. If you try to run those multiplications in parallel, you only oversubscribe your CPU

Comment: using LinearAlgebra;  LinearAlgebra.BLAS.set_num_threads(Threads.nthreads());

Comment: Don't start using multithreading until the general performance issues have been fixed: don't work in global scope, don't use global variables, operate along columns not rows. And please make an MWE.

Comment: @DNF I could transpose everything to operate along columns, would that be sufficient or is that more of a hack?

Comment: Depends. Just a lazy `transpose` doesn't help, because the underlying data would still be oriented the wrong way. Do you have control of how the data is generated, if so you should set it up to produce column oriented data in the first place.